# How do I create an Object from a firebase document that also has a collection?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Is there a way to make an Object conform to Codable that has an array of other Objects?

I got following Object:

```
struct Album: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let artist: String
    let songs: [AlbumSong]
    let releaseDate: Date
    let price: Int
    let albumImageUrl: String
    var unlocked: Bool
}
```

I try to fetch my Data from firebase Database and create an Album but it needs to conform to Codable. I guess the problem is the array of AlbumSong

```
    @State var albums: [Album] = []
FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("songs").getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                return
            }
            self.albums = documents.compactMap { document -> Album? in
                do {
                    return try document.data(as: Album.self)
                } catch {
                    return nil
                }
            }
```

My firebase Database looks like this:
[image]

[image]

This is what AlbumSong looks like:

```
struct AlbumSong: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let duration: TimeInterval
    var image: String
    let artist: String
    let track: String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `Codable` all properties of the type also have to be codable. Most of the Swift primitive types (`String`,`Int`,....) do. For your `Album` to conform you have to conform `AlbumSong` to `Codable`

```
struct AlbumSong: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let duration: TimeInterval
    var image: String
    let artist: String
    let track: String
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This atleast solves my issues of Album not conforming to Codable. But my albums array is still empty after fetching and I don't understand why

Comment: Trying to fetch a document by id works:  `FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("albums").document("BuFS1v3OjZ4aCXlaoYWg").getDocument { snapshot, error in
            print(snapshot?.data())
        }` This printed everything from the Database but the collection of AlbumSongs.

Comment: @AdamLeet glad I could help. Regarding your comment: It seems to me that the issue is not related to the question you asked above. Please create a new question for that and add enough details so we can better understand what is going on.